# Extending session in another application

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am not sure if the title is correct, but that is the closest terms that I can use based on my current understanding on what I would like to achieve. But I am including an image so that it will be easier for me to explain it.

[image: Proposed architecture]

Basically, I am trying to divide the application based on its function, the first one is the color red, that will serve as the login page with homepage or mainpage that will have several functions:

- check for user authentication(user & pass)
- after successfully logged in, the application will then check the user access level whether to redirect him to the transaction module(collection of sub applications) or to the file maintenance.

I have made all the applications but at the moment it is as 'one application', so my main problem are:

1. how can I extend my session after logging in RED to BLUE or to YELLOW when I am being redirected.
2. And how can I redirect or call the controller from RED to BLUE or to YELLOW? or if I am not calling via controller from one application to another rather using url, how or what is it called?
3. The flow can only be from RED to BLUE, and RED to YELLOW, but not BLUE to YELLOW.

*Note: all 3 applications are separated*

Thanks in advance

*ADDED: for example, so far I can only remember signing up once which was in stackoverflow, but when I click on 'server fault', 'database administrators' and etc in stackoverflow associated sites, they still retain my session without me re-logging.

Or when logging in gmail, I can just straight go to youtube and now I am logged in youtube as well? That is what I want to achieve in this question.

Answer (score 1):

If a user is logged in - then with every click - you have to confirm the credentials. Thats either with a cookie session or a token (url or form field) or in the http header. After you have confirmed the user - then you let them in to your class and methods.

If you have to redirect then you set the cookie session - and then redirect. The controller you redirect to will be able to read the session cookie. But usually you are going to redirect to kick someone out because their credential did not pass.

Try and set up your diagrams based on the type of user and what they can do - User, Admin, Owner are types of users. And then - what are the users acting on. Some Users maybe able to create something and update but not delete. So if define the roles, you immediately separate out the security concerns.

Each role gets at least one controller - so all the methods in the class have the same level of validation. You are not mixing methods for simple users Versus methods for a super admin. Let the needs of the specific user define what methods are in the class.

==== edit

oh now you mention single sign on? :-)
This might be of interest: Codeigniter oauth 2  https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-oauth2

handles: Facebook, Foursquare, GitHub, Google, PayPal, Instagram, Soundcloud, Windows Live, YouTube

Comment: The user role is finished, but to implement it into this 3 day application, how do I pass that in code likewise? also how can the BLUE/YELLOW app can detect whether the cookie session being passed to them is correct as well?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the correct term for it. It is SSO. Just going around looking for tutorials at the moment, so far I am reading this:

http://thinkmoult.com/use-codeigniter-openid-library-to-integrate-openid/